# Ubuntu 16.04.3 chromium get rid of "Adobe Flash Player was blocked because it was out of date"

Tags: 16.04, flash, chromium

I have the above issue since a few weeks, when I click Run this time, flash just works, but I want to get rid of the annoying message.

I have searched the internet and the consensus seems to be to use chrome://components and click update. However in my case the flash plugin **does not show in the list**.

I have installed the adobe-flashplugin from the Canonical partners source.

The details of this installation are:

```
~$ apt show adobe-flashplugin 
Package: adobe-flashplugin
Version: 1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
Priority: optional
Section: web
Maintainer: DL-Flash Player Ubuntu <FlashPlayerUbuntu@adobe.com>
Installed-Size: 38,1 MB
Provides: flashplugin-nonfree
Depends: wget, fontconfig, libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.11), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) | libnspr4-0d (>= 1.8.0.10), libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) | libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~beta3), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.3), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxext6, libxrender1, libxt6
Recommends: adobe-flash-properties-gtk (= 1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) | adobe-flash-properties-kde (= 1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
Suggests: firefox | chromium-browser, x-ttcidfont-conf, msttcorefonts, ttf-bitstream-vera | ttf-dejavu, ttf-xfree86-nonfree, xfs (>= 1:1.0.1-5), libnspr4-0d, libnss3-1d
Conflicts: flashplayer-mozilla, flashplugin (<< 6), flashplugin-downloader, flashplugin-installer, xfs (<< 1:1.0.1-5)
Replaces: flashplugin (<< 6)
Npp-File: libflashplayer.so
Npp-Mimetype: application/x-shockwave-flash
Npp-Applications: ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384, 92650c4d-4b8e-4d2a-b7eb-24ecf4f6b63a, aa5ca914-c309-495d-91cf-3141bbb04115
Npp-Description: Adobe Flash Plugin (http://www.adobe.com)
Npp-Name: Adobe Flash Plugin
Download-Size: 10,3 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily/partner amd64 Packages
Description: Adobe Flash Player plugin
 Adobe® Flash® Player is a cross-platform, browser-based application runtime
 that provides uncompromised viewing of expressive applications, content, and
 videos across browsers and operating systems.
 .
 This package provides plugins compatible with both Chromium and Mozilla based
 web browsers
```

Any help removing the popup would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's Google Chrome you have, it has Flash built-in, and `adobe-flashplugin` is not used. The latter is for Chromium and Mozilla based browsers.

Comment: Looks like I have chromium. About page says "Chromium Version 60.0.3112.78 (Developer Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)". Updated title and tags accordingly.

Comment: If so, fully update your system and try again. An update, if needed (and there was one recently that I'm suspecting you didn't install) is provide along with all the other system updates. Chrome, OTOH, has the required Flash update inside the new version.

Comment: I already did that. Did both apt upgrade, apt dist-upgrade, reboot. Remove flash and reinstall flash, reboot again. No luck.

Comment: Why is your Chromium version so old? Current chromium in 16.04 is version 64, not 60.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to configure the permission for flash for that specific website. Google explains how to do that in [Google Chrome Help | Change site permissions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662).

Second paragraph *Change settings for a specific site* says click on the lock to the left of the web address and change the permission setting. Set it to never ask or block it at all.

This way the message won't show up. Works for me on Deezer.

I did this on Chromium 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 17.10 (64-Bit) but I guess it's the same on 16.04 with a recent version of Chromium/Chrome.